# Running Python script from PHP starting script, but not ending it

Tags: php, python, opencv

I'm trying to run Python script from PHP. I already tried to use: system(), exec() and shell_exec() functions. Now my PHP is looking like:

```
<?php
system('./main.py');
echo 'succes';
?>
```

I made some print() function in my Python script and found, that it stops on this line:

```
QueryImgBGR = cv2.imread(image_path)
```

PHP *echo()* is working, altrough the *system()* function is not ended. Running Python script from console is working.

I'm working on Debian 4.9.30 with Python 3.5.3(using numpy, cv2 and os libraries) and PHP 7.2.4(system(), shell_exec(), exec() functions unlocked).

**EDIT:** Someway print() function in Python prints on new line, but the system() function prints them all on one line through space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system() call only gives you the last line of command output, and it is the return value of the call.  So you want to capture it.

```
$response = system('./main.py');
echo 'success - response = ' . $response;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing at this, I edited question. Unfortunately this didn't helped me.